# Find the Content-type of the incoming request in Spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, content-type

I have a Spring-Boot controller application that will be called by the front-end. The Spring-boot `@PostMapping` would accept the `XML` and `JSON`. I want to call different methods based on the `Content-Type`.

Is there a way to check what is the incoming content type?

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyController {
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/generator", consumes = {"application/json", "application/xml"}, produces = "application/json")
    public String generate(@RequestBody String input) {
        try {
            System.out.println("INPUT CONTENT TYPE : ");
            if(contentType == "application/xml")
            {
                //Call Method-1
            }else if(contentType == "application/json"){
                //Call Method-2
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

As we can see the `RestController` method accepts `XML and JSON`. I want to check whats the incoming `Content-type` is based on its need to make different decisions. Can someone please explain to me how to do it?

Please Note:
I am aware that I can create different methods to handle XML and JSON but I would like to do it in a single method so it would be easy and efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add [RequestHeader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html) with its name `Content-type`:

```
public String generate(@RequestBody String input, @RequestHeader("Content-type") String contentType)
```

> Annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a web request header.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers
```

inside param of your generate() methode for get all Header come from the client.

After that, just check the

> Content-Type

value