# Java/Quarkus how to identify the Content-type of the incoming request

Tags: java, rest, quarkus, media-type

I am developing a Rest-API application using Java/Quarkus. My POST API accepts XML/JSON contents. I would like to identify the type of MediaType of the incoming data based on which I need to make a request to another URL by setting the appropriate `content-type`.

Following is the code I have so far:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;

@Path("/api")
public class DataGenerator {

    @Path("/generate")
    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String generateData(String input) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create("https://example.com/example"))
                .header("content-type", "application/json")
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(input))
                .build();
        return HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()).body();
    }
}
```

As you can see my `input` can be `XML/JSON`. If `JSON` then I would like to set `header("content-type", "application/json")` else if the `input` is `XML` then I would like to set `header("content-type", "application/xml")`.

Based on the `content-type` the URL `https://example.com/example` calls out a different method to generate the response.

As of now, the function is working accurately for JSON but I am unable to handle the XML Input. Can someone please let me know how can I find the incoming Input MediaType?

I have this question for spring-boot ([Find the Content-type of the incoming request in Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68800947/7584240)) but I am unable to understand how to do it for the Quarkus-based application? Do I need to pass again from front-end or there is some Quarkus default way?

Comment: What do you mean you "found" that question? You **asked** that question.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes that was for Spring-boot. Now I would like to know how the same can be done for the `Quarkus` application. Do I need to pass again from front-end itself?

Comment: Read the documentation. Quarkus and Spring are very similar, and HTTP remains the same whichever you use.

Comment: @Kayaman The problem is that if I add another parameter something like this `generateData(String input, String contentType)` in `Quarkus` then I get the exception `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource method java.lang.String generate(java.lang.String input, java.lang.String contentType)` which was not the case when I was using the `Spring-Boot`. So I am unable to send via front-end as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, this is set in the `Content-Type` header. So to pull this header you can do this (this uses JAX-RS annotation `javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam`):

```java
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public String hello(@HeaderParam("Content-Type") String contentType, String data) {
        return String.format("Data: %s%nContent-Type: %s", data, contentType);
    }
```